# Using wget to download Vertica

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wget, vertica

I need to download Vertica Server Package on my Ubuntu 14.04 Server. It's a password protected file with a very long download link that starts with 'h30537.ww3.hpe.com'. Unfortunately when i try to use wget to download it I just get 'Failed:name or service not known' and 'unable to resolve host address' errors. I wonder what could be causing this error, I can access this link on my browser just fine and I know i can connect to the internet on my Linux server because I can ping google.

The command I ran was `wget --user user@mail.com --password pass -O short_name.iso 'h30537.ww3.hpe.com/blablablalong link'`

Comment: I suspect that the correct hostname is `h30537.www3.hpe.com` - could this be the culprit?

Answer (score 0):

It won't work, but if you have HP account(Vertica support account), oyu can use their ftp server to download using wget.

**Example:**

```
wget --user vertica_patches --password xxxxx ftp://customers.vertica.com/7.2/7.2.2-3/vertica-7.2.2-3.x86_64.RHEL6.rpm
```